# Passing variable from C# to PowerShell does not work

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to pass a C# object to PowerShell so I can provide the main UI with status updates. I have seen several posts regarding this on SO, but none of them seem to help solving my issue.

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
runspace.Open();

runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("LogReporter", this.LogReporter);

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Collection<PSObject> objects = pipeline.Invoke();
```

And in the PowerShell script I want to access the LogReporter (base type: `System.Windows.Window`) like seen in the snippet below

```
$RunningInstances= @(Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.InstanceStatus.ToString() -eq "Running" })
$LogReporter.ReportProgress($RunningInstances.Count.ToString() + " instances running currently...")
```

However, all I got is

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

I tried to list all members of the $LogReporter variable, but the result is

```
No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet.
```

This means, the `$LogReporter` variable is `null`. The questions now are: why and how to fix this?

Please be aware that the code was simplified slightly for better readability but shows the necessary and failing parts.

Any ideas on what's going wrong? Do I have to register my `LogReporter` type somehow?

I appreciate any help!

**Solution**

I had a a typo and the variable in the C# code did not match the one in the PowerShell script. There is nothing wrong with my code sample here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full working sample which shows you the problem. The problem is not in LogReporter variable, but in "$_.InstanceStatus.ToString()" part. InstanceStatus is null in your case, and ToString() throws the exception above. In code below I just removed ToString() call, and you see "0 instances running" message from your LogReporter.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        new ScriptRunner().Run();   
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }        
}

class ScriptRunner {
    public ScriptRunner() {
        this.LogReporter = new LogReporter();
    }

    public void Run() {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
        runspace.Open();



        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$RunningInstances=@(Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.InstanceStatus -eq \"Running\"})");
        runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("LogReporter", this.LogReporter);
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$LogReporter.ReportProgress($RunningInstances.Count.ToString()+\" instances running currently...\")");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Collection<PSObject> objects = pipeline.Invoke();            
    }

    public LogReporter LogReporter { get; private set; }

}

class LogReporter
{
    public void ReportProgress(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `InstanceStatus` is not null. The child items are BizTalk objects and `InstanceStatus` is an enum. If I don't try to log stuff, the scripts works as expected, but I don't have any progress messages then.

Comment: That is quite strange, since code above is tested. What will happen if you just execute following script: "$LogReporter.ReportProgress(\"0 instances running currently...\")"? So, if you skip $RunningInstances=... line entirely.

Comment: Also interesting if example above works as it is for you.

Comment: I tested your example and I can see the console output as expected. Also when modifying the class `LogReporter` to `LogReporter : Window`. I try to further modify the example to my current tool state and check the differences.

Comment: I had a typo in one of my variables. The C# name did not match the script variable name.